# dropzone.js with HTML element

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Couldn't found in the documentation anything about using dropzone.js with simple HTML element.
I'm using it for uploading files and I'm trying to add this functionality: when dropped an HTML element in it, I will be using the data in the html to do something (i.e. move already uploaded files).
Tried to drag the HTML element but I notice that the "drop" event is fired multiple times. When dropping files from OS it is fired once... I can't understand why it's happening!
Thank you for your suggestions.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(target, {
  url: "./fake", // fake, must be indicated for the plugin but I do not use it
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  clickable: false,
});

myDropzone.on("drop", (ev) => {
    //do something
})
```

Comment: you can also do it using addEventListener's drag events like dragstart and so on.

Comment: sorry, what do yo mean? i need to listen to the drop event but I can't understand why is being fired multiple times on a single drop...

Comment: no, i mean you are using dropzone.js for drag-drop event ...this you can do using event listener also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me.

Forgot to use stopImmediatePropagation.

```
myDropzone.on("drop", (ev) => {
    ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
    //do something
})
```